# C how to allocate struct to struct?

Tags: c, struct

The following code gives me a Compile error "`incompatible types at assignment`"

File 1:

```
struct x{ 
  int a; 
  int b; 
  int c;
};
```

File 2:

```
static struct x d;
void copyStructVal(){
  d-> a = 1;
  d-> b = 2;
  d-> c = 3;
}
x getStruct(){
 copyStructVal();
 return d;
}
```

File 3:

```
static struct x e;
void copy(){
 e = getStruct();
}
```

I've searched for this and can't find the answer. Can I do it with a Pointer? (I'm a amateur in C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, you need to write `struct` behind the name of a structure, unless you `typedef` it. In other words:

```
x getStruct(){
```

Must be:

```
struct x getStruct(){
```

Since you wrote it in the rest of the code, I guess it is a typo.

On top of that, you have to fix these 3 lines, since `d` is not a pointer:

```
  d-> a = 1;
  d-> b = 2;
  d-> c = 3;
```

They should be:

```
  d.a = 1;
  d.b = 2;
  d.c = 3;
```

Comment: Ty the Problem was solved but now i got a nother Error: "syntax error - token "=" deleted" ( e = getStruct() ).  If i delete this symbol, the error ist gone, but is it right?

Comment: @serc: `e = getStruct()` should work. Maybe post this as a new question with the full code :-)